# get_locale() is different from $locale

Tags: functions, multi-language

for a language switcher I need to change the get_locale value to the needed language which works great using this code in my functions.php

```
add_filter( 'locale', 'set_my_locale' );
function set_my_locale( $lang ) {
    $lang= 'en_US';
    return $lang;
}
```

`echo get_locale()` results in `en_US` as needed, but `$locale` still shows the value defined in the `wp-config.php`? Using the code below did not help either:

```
function set_locale_frontend($locale)
{
    $lang= 'en_US';
    return $lang;
}
add_filter('locale', 'set_locale_frontend');
```

What am I doing wrong or am I missing to do? Please help! Thanks very much!

Comment: Where and how are you using `$locale`?

Comment: Just checking the value for `$locale` because this loads the correct translation file then, right?

Comment: But where are you checking it?